# How can I get client's IP address?

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, ip-address

I am writing a web application with PHP and Javascript that uses [Ratchet WebSockets](http://socketo.me) for communication data between server and clients, but I need to get client's IP address.

In Ratchet WebSockets have a function "onOpen" that it give an object of "ConnectionInterface":

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn){
    $this->clients->attach($conn);
    echo "new Connection is connected...({$conn->resourceId})\n";
}
```

It only has a resource id. How can I get the IP address of this connection?

Comment: https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/126

Answer (score 9):

```
$conn->remoteAddress
```

Try this.

Comment: It's a shame they don't give the port though, the same client can be open multiple times over different ports

Answer (score 1):

`$conn` variable contains following two fields:
`$conn->resourceId` and `$conn->remoteAddress`

[Reference URL](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/126)

Answer (score -3):

Try this.
`$ClientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; echo $ClientIP;` echos the client's IP Address `98.1.xx.x` You can find the reference on $_SERVER at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: That's for a bog-standard HTTP request, not this.